# Discord.py Creating continually changing role color

Tags: python, discord.py

I added an option to my bot to change the role color after some time. But, after a while, this option stops working. How can I make this option work all the time?

```
from asyncio.tasks import create_task
import discord
from discord import client
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
from discord.utils import get
import os
from keep_alive import keep_alive

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot jest gotowy!")

@bot.command()
async def r1(ctx):
    while True:
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=869949352246902846)
        await role.edit(color=0xff0000, reason="red")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.25)
        await role.edit(color=0xcc7306, reason="orange")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.25)
        await role.edit(color=0xfbff03, reason="yellow")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.25)
        await role.edit(color=0x2fff00, reason="green")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.25)
        await role.edit(color=0x0073ff, reason="blue")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.25)
        await role.edit(color=0xae00ff, reason="purple")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.25)
```

Comment: These types of 'rainbow roles' are **against discord's TOS**, this is because it is an overload of the API. Based on a quick search, the rate limit for editing roles seems to be 1000 requests per 24 hours, meaning about 41 requests every hour.

Answer (score 2):

It stops working because you're being ratelimited by Discord for spamming their API. Don't do this.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that discord is rate-limiting you because you're spamming their API, this could get you banned but if you really want it to change the colours I recommend making the time in-between a lot higher such as 40-60 seconds. Overall this is a very risky thing to do.